# Should S3 bucket be in the same region as EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

we have our bucket created in the Amazon-East region. We have our EC2 instances in Amazon-West region. We have around hundred EC2 instances downloading 50GB of data each from the S3 bucket. Does having a bucket in the Amazon-West region improve the download speeds drastically?

Answer (score 3):

If you have them in different regions you will pay a transfer fee between regions and the transfer speed will be lower.

If moving the instances or the data is not an option (or you are looking at a bridge solution until you move them) check out the S3 Cross Region Replication feature: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html
You will pay the transfer fee only once and you will enjoy same region/high speed transfer speeds (you will need to point the instances at the in-region bucket and you will pay a storage fee for keeping a copy of the data)

Comment: thanks a lot Mircea for the information. Enabled cross-region replication.

Answer (score 1):

Yes having them in the same region will improve the download speed quite drastically. I think it will also reduce your bandwidth fees.

Comment: @Mircea if you have a comment add it as a comment. That is not an appropriate reason to edit someone else's answer.

Comment: thought that it made the answer overall better. If you don't think it should be part of the answer that's fine.

Comment: @Mircea that just isn't an appropriate use of the edit function. It's like you are putting that in there and making it look like I said it. It's good additional information that should be added as a comment.

Comment: that's fine. seen this done to my answers in the past and it personally does not bother me as long as it improves the quality of the answer.